# create new control from errorProvider

Tags: c#, user-controls, custom-controls, errorprovider

I want to create a control `MessageProvider` just like `ErrorProvider`..what I did is, created a class and inherited from ErrorProvider..

But now problem is, instead of `SetError` and `GetError` methods, I want to have `SetMessage` and `GetMessage`..and those `SetError` and `GetError` methods should not be part of MessageProvider class..

How can I create a new control `MessageProvider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encapsulate the ErrorProvider within your new control.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hide public methods from an inherited class as there is no private inheritance in the [CTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  You can, however, easily add the SetMessage() and GetMessage() methods to your derived class and implement the desired functionality.

Your other option is to roll your own MessageProvider class that implements (mimics) only the desired functionality of ErrorProvider.  This is probably more trouble than it's worth.  I'd just derive and live with all the inherited functionality.

Comment: The other option would be to encapsulate the ErrorProvider instead of inheriting from it.